# React datepicker for user choose start date or due date or range date (from start date to due date)

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, date-range

I'm looking for a lib reactjs datepicker for my management task website (similar [Clickup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5lHu.png) web app). User can choose `duedate` or `startdate` or a range date (from `startdate` to `duedate`).

Logic same as clickup web app logic:

- If user only have `duedate`, user can choose a range date from `duedate` to date before `duedate`.
- If user only have `startdate`, user can choose a range date from `startdate` to date after `startdate`.
- If user have `startdate` and `duedate`, user can choose a range date from `startdate` to date after `duedate`.

Here is a picture of Clickup picker:

[image]

In future, I will set recurring logic with that picker. So if lib support recurring logic will be helpful for me.

I'm looking for a datetime picker lib support for startDate and endDate similar ClickUp web (app.clickup.com). It's for task management web app.Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Can you please give clarity on your issue? I don't get it...

Comment: I'm looking for a datetime picker lib support for `startDate` and `endDate` similar ClickUp web (https://app.clickup.com/). It's for task management web app.